# How do I perform a change in order of integration here?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, iterated-integrals

I have a function $$\int^1_{y=0}\int^1_{x=y}e^{x^2}dx\ dy$$

Which I want to perform a change in order of integration. I have plotted the graph:

[image]

And it seems it's the area bounded by the y-axis and x-axis. The answer I know is $(e-1)/2$ but it doesn't make sense since a quick check can tell the area of the triangle under is $1/2.$

The limits to be changed to is:
$$\int^1_{x=0}\int^x_{y=0}e^{x^2}dy\ dx$$
Giving
$$ \left[ \frac{1}{2}e^{x^2} \right]^1_0 = \frac{1}{2}(e-1)$$

Comment: You would get $1/2$ if the function you were integrating were $1$, not $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: However, wouldn't the original integral limits bound me to the area of the triangle still? Does that mean the "curvy triangle" is actually the triangle which area I'm finding?

Comment: Note that we are integrating $f(x,y)=e^{x^2}$ over the triangular domain. The function $f(x,y)=e^{x^2}$ should be plotted as a surface in 3D. What we are calculating is the volume between the trinagular domain and the surface $f(x,y)=e^{x^2}$.

Comment: Very strangely, I can see why it's seen as the "volume" since it's like a pyramid which base lies on the curvy surface. But I can't reconcile this volume with the fact that some $dV$ is always expressed as integral of $dx\ dy\ dz$ why are volumes found using integrals 4D then?

Answer (score 2):

You need to think to the integral as

$$\int^1_{y=0}\int^1_{x=y}f(x,y)\,dx\ dy$$

with $f(x,y)=e^{x^2}$, thus we would obtain the value of $\frac12$ for $f(x,y)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int^1_0 \left( \int^1_y e^{x^2} \, dx\right) dy = \iint\limits_{\{\,(x,y)\,:\, 0 \,\le\,y\,\le\,x\,\le\,1\,\}} e^{x^2} \, d(x,y) = \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^x e^{x^2} \, dy \right) dx
$$

Look carefully at these inequalities:
$$
0\le y\le x \le 1.
$$
Here's another way to say what those inequalities say:

$y$ goes from $0$ to $1.$ For any fixed value of $y$ between $0$ and $1,\,\,$ $x$ goes from $y$ to $1.$

$x$ goes from $0$ to $1.$ For any fixed value of $x$ between $0$ and $1,\,\,$ $y$ goes from $0$ to $x.$